# How can I play a youtube video [selenium]

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to play/pause a YouTube video in my python script but `driver.find_element_by_name("body").send_keys('keys.SPACE')` 
does not work

As it does not work I'm using pyautogui.press("space") instead but I have to be in the page. Using the selenium method is it possible to send the key signal without having YouTube focused?

Comment: Space is the "works most of the time" key. The official keyboard shortcut is "k".

Comment: it outputs an error " Message: Unable to locate element: [name="body"]
"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try finding the video and using `.send_keys('keys.SPACE')` or `.click()` methods which can be performed even if you don't have that exact window focused

Here's my code. I found the video by id `movie_player`. The code opens the page, waits 10 seconds, plays the video and stops it after a second. Hope it helps

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Max/Desktop/Code/Selenium/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXUAyRRkI6k')
# wait for the page to load everything (works without it)
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(1)
video = driver.find_element_by_id('movie_player')
video.send_keys(Keys.SPACE) #hits space
time.sleep(1)
video.click()               #mouse click
```

Comment: It outputs this error
"selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element <div class="ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay-image"> is not clickable at point (464,320) because another element <button class="ytp-large-play-button ytp-button"> obscures it
"

Comment: Gotcha,
webpage = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body"); webpage.send_keys("K")
works too